# Submit form with ng-submit and output fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form on a page of my website with a form and upon pressing the submit button I want to output that data to another page of the website. I can get the value by $scope.title in my controller but I am unsure how I would go about storing it (array?) and output it back to the other page. I am using angularJS.

form:

```
<div ng-app = "app">
        <form ng-controller = "body" ng-submit="Display()">
            <p>Title</p>
            <input type="text" ng-model="title">
            <p>Author</p>
            <input type="text" ng-model="author">
            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
        </form>
</div>
```

controller:

```
app.controller("body", function ($scope) {
    $scope.setPost = () => {
        $scope.Array = [];
        $scope.Display = () => {
            $scope.Array.push($scope.title);
        }
    };
});
```

post:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in Array">
     {{title}}
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data  and  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: first change `{{title}}` with `{{value}}` in `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the below code, and also check [this plunker link](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/0ebbNcrdXGtk8FC0) for your given example working scenario.

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.Array = [];
});

app.controller('body', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.Display = () => {
    var arrayValue = {
      title: $scope.title,
      author: $scope.author
    }
    $rootScope.Array.push(arrayValue);
  }
});
```

**Template:**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form ng-controller="body" ng-submit="Display()">
      <p>Title</p>
      <input type="text" ng-model="title">
      <p>Author</p>
      <input type="text" ng-model="author">
      <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
    <div ng-repeat="value in Array">
      {{value.title}} by {{value.author}}
    </div>
  </body>
```